# How to stub a module function that is called from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sinon

My `module.ts` file has 2 functions:

```
export async function foo() {
    var barVal = await bar();
    doSomethingWithBarVal(barVal);
}

export async function bar(): Bar {
    return await somethingAsync();
}
```

In my tests I want to `stub` bar() and return a `mock` for `Bar` (the returned value of `bar()`)

My current test looks like this:

```
var module = require('module.ts');
var myStub = sinon.stub(module, 'bar').resolves(myMock);
await foo();
expect(myStub.calledOnce);
```

However, the `expect` always fails and the 'real' `bar()` is called.
If I call `bar()` directly from my test, then the stub **is called** but I want to test the whole flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are stubbing module object (`exports` since you are using commonjs `require` in your test) while your `foo` function uses `bar` available in module scope.

To fix this you have a few options here.

## 1. Quick and dirty

Use `exports.bar` instead  of `bar` in `foo`

```
export async function foo() {
    var barVal = await exports.bar();
    doSomethingWithBarVal(barVal);
}
```

This approach is actually a hack that uses the fact that your module will be transpiled to commonjs format. Which might be not true someday but kinda works for now.

## 2. Embrace static nature of ES modules

Embrace the fact that ES modules are static. Make your function "testable again" by explicitly allowing to specify `bar` as its argument

```
export async function foo(_bar = bar) {
    var barVal = await _bar();
    doSomethingWithBarVal(barVal);
}

// test.js
await foo(mockBarImplementation)
```

## 3. Advanced

Use some `IoC/DI` implementation. For example [typescript-ioc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-ioc)